# The prime factorization of $15$ when finding the number of solutions to $15=a^{2}+b^{2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-factorization

> Find the number of solutions to $15=a^{2}+b^{2}$.

My professor told us to write $15$ in the form $2^{a}p_{1}^{t_{1}}\cdots p_{n}^{t_{n}}q_{1}^{c_{1}}\cdots q_{m}^{c_{m}}$, and if any $t_{i}$ is odd, then there are no solutions $(a,b)$, and if all $t_{i}$ are even, then there are $4\prod _{i=1}^{m}(c_{i}+1)$ solutions.

My question is: What do $p_{i}$ and $q_{i}$ stand for? I know they are prime numbers, but why are they written using different letters? Is it because all $p_{i} \equiv 3$ (mod $4$) and $q_{i}\equiv 1$ (mod $4$)? But that wouldn't make sense to me because $15=3\cdot 5$ and $3\equiv 3$ (mod $4$) is not true.

Comment: What do you mean by "$3\equiv3$ (mod 4) is not true"?

Comment: Consider another title for the question please.

Comment: @alex.jordan Isn't $3\equiv -1$ (mod $4$), or am I wrong with this... There is some theorem that says if a prime $p\equiv 3$ (mod $4$), then $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: $3$ _is_ congruent to $-1$ mod $4$. And it is _also_ congruent to $3$ mod $4$. It sounds like you may not yet be familiar enough with the fundamentals to get to the bigger question about $15$. Modular arithmetic is about taking the integers $\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots$ and grouping them into classes. If you are doing it mod $4$, the classes are $\{\ldots,-4,0,4,\ldots\}, \{\ldots,-3,1,5,\ldots\}, \{\ldots,-2,2,6,\ldots\}, \{\ldots,-1,3,7,\ldots\},$. And "$3$" is just a shorthand for $\{\ldots,-1,3,7,\ldots\}$. And so is "$-1$". The $\equiv$ symbol means either side is in the same class.

Comment: In practice, $a\equiv b$ (mod $c$) means that $c$ divides $a-b$. So since $4$ divides $3-3$, then $3\equiv3$ (mod$4$). And also since $4$ divides $3-(-1)$, then $3\equiv-1$ (mod$4$).

Comment: @alex.jordan Oh, wow! I am not very good at modulo arithmetic. Thanks so much for reminding these facts! I now totally understand now that I know what modulo arithmetic is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are primes and $p_i \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $q_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  The point is the [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) says that primes $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ cannot be written as the sum of two squares and implies that numbers which have an odd number of factors of a prime $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ cannot be written as a sum of two squares.  Certainly $3$ cannot.  If you do what your teacher says you write for $15\  p_1=1, t_1=1,q_1=5,c_1=1$.  Because $t_1=1$ is odd you cannot write $15$ as the sum of two squares and indeed you cannot.